# Set application.properties at runtime

Tags: java, application.properties

I need to get my.application.dev, my.application.qa or my.application depending on the environment where is running:

I have my application.properties like this:

```
application.prod=my.application
application.qa=my.application.qa
application.dev=my.application.dev
application.property=${application.${env.name}}
```

And this is my code:

```
InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
// Let's say that I have a environment var to determinate if it's running in dev, qa or prod
// At this point, I do something like this String env = System.getenv("envName");
```

** What could I do here is to set ${env.name}} with env**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(input);
String myValue = props.getProperty("application.property");
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Here's an idea: Since `Properties` doesn't do `${}` substitutions, *you* should **write some code** to do that.

Comment: You don't need to complicate things with `application.property=${application.${env.name}}`. Try approach suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In `application.properties` just define:

```
application.prod=my.application
application.qa=my.application.qa
application.dev=my.application.dev
```

Then read the needed property:

```
String env = System.getProperty("envName");
try (InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.load(input);
  String value = props.getProperty("application." + env);
  System.out.println(value);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```